# Can drawing views in Solidworks be scaled without keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: solidworks

I'm making weldment drawings that involve a long W-Beam with a number of flanges welded to the web. The problem is that because the weldment is so large, lines become difficult distinguish from each other when the weldment is scaled to fit the page.

What I want to be able to do is scale the X- and Y-axes of the view independently so lines become clear while still fitting everything on the page, like SDS/2 does. Solidworks does not appear to have this feature.

Comment: As far as I know, that is not supported in solidworks. That's probably because it is not a generally accepted drafting practice. Is it possible that break lines would solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible, as it would distort the part. You may be able to achieve an acceptable view with the following techniques:

- Broken Views- These would allow you to cut out the long sections between the flanges allowing one to visualize the whole beam.
- Hiding lines - with a zoomed out view you can hide the lines that are blending together to only show the outer edges of the w. This allows you to show the entire beam to scale.
- An angled view- If you turn off perspective and view the beam from the end, then rotate by a small angle you can effectively get a changed aspect ratio, but it will be obvious that it is an angled view.